# Which dice do I use for ordinary feats in "Don't Rest Your Head"?

Tags: dont-rest-your-head

I understand the use of Exhaustion dice in minor and major uses of Exhaustion talents as well as Madness talents, but what about ordinary feats?

My PCs will be hunted by an evil pharmaceutical company who have ordinary mooks with tasers and such. (I'll rate these at 1 to 3 Pain dice depending upon the number of assailants).  If a player is wrestling with an attacker or trying to flee a kidnapper *without* using their talents, do exhaustion dice count at all? Or just discipline dice?

The minor and major talent uses *improve the successes* of Exhaustion dice, so it makes sense to me that without using a talent, you get to add "unimproved" successes from Exhaustion dice on such challenges. And it also makes sense that by fighting harder you get more tired.  However, adding four Exhaustion dice to the three Discipline dice can give PC's an astounding success at something they don't have as an explicit talent.

This is important to the scenario, in which the PC's are caught in a pincer between horrors in the Mad City and hunters in normal reality.

Answer (score 4):

Good news! Most of the rolls you'll ever be making when there's some Pain on the line are going to look about the same! (This is a summary of the Player Dice section on p.10)

- You always roll however many of your three Discipline dice remain, and the permanent Madness dice that have replaced them.
- You always roll your current Exhaustion rating in Exhaustion dice, because the closer you get to the edge of exhaustion the more capable you become at everything, not just your Exhaustion Talent.

In addition!

- Assuming it's not already topped out at 6, you can always increase your Exhaustion level by exactly one to roll an extra Exhaustion die, even if you're not doing something to activate your Major Exhaustion Talent. Because see above about becoming more capable.
- You can always add up to six red, shiny, candy-like Madness dice, even if you're not explicitly activating some superhuman feature of your Madness Talent. I know it might not seem like it makes logical sense for it to apply to the current situation, and madness is well-known for making strict logical sense, but that's just game mechanics for you.

This can lead to a ridiculous number of successes, as measured against strictly Sleeper opposition, but the usual resolution rules also still apply. If Exhaustion or Madness dominate, you inch closer to crashing or snapping (and in the case of Madness, also lose some control based on the response), which is the price you pay for relying on your powers.

There are two circumstances where this changes.

- If you ever fall asleep (see Crashing, p. 12) and survive the experience (see Crashing, p. 12) you'll have exactly one Discipline die and no access to anything else until you've been awake long enough to get exhausted again, at which point your powers return in full.
- If you're ever flashing back to the times before you went through tired and out the other side, and it becomes necessary to butt heads with Pain, all you'll have are your three Discipline dice (see Flashback, p. 34).

Comment: Checking the rules shows that you are right about Madness dice not requiring an invocation of the Madness talent.  I might house-rule it that way since this would reinforce the surreal horror of the game.